# Algorithm to extract the underlying table names of a SQL Query

Tags: sql, algorithm

I am trying to fetch the different table names used in a SQL query with a basic algorithm.
Does anyone of you have already done that?

I am having trouble in finding a global algorithm that is working with the whole SQL grammar as there are several way to use the FROM statement e.g.`FROM table1 as t1` or `FROM table1 t1` or `FROM table1` etc.

I don't have any target programming language yet, but I want an algorithm that I could adapt to any language and platform, so I don't want to use any library. It need to be compatible with Oracle and Sybase SQL.

Comment: In every case of the FROM clause you used, the table name is immediately after a 'FROM '. Why not just use that to parse?

Comment: Are you limited to a particular subset of SQL?  Are you just referring to ANSI sql, or vendor specific extensions (Oracle, SQL Server, etc)?

Comment: @RQDQ - Yes, Sybase and Oracle

Comment: In Microsoft Sql Server, you can get the execution plan for your query in XML.  That would be a lot easier to parse than trying to parse the SQL directly.  Maybe Sybase and Oracle have something similar?

Comment: @SupremeDud: There are exceptions to that pattern: `...FROM (SELECT ...)`. But it's a valid approach.

Comment: Are you going to take into account only SELECT queries? For, as I'm sure you know, there are others, like UPDATE. Also, some statements allow different syntax, like `DELETE table` and `DELETE FROM table`, or `INSERT table` and `INSERT INTO table`.

Comment: @ Andriy M - Yes, only select queries.

Comment: You'll also have to deal with JOINs where you'll have additional table names which are not preceded by the FROM keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that there is only one table being accessed in the query, then you can just grab the table name from the FROM clause, after the FROM keyword. (You'll have to account for the various ways that table name could be aliased and account for possible subqueries.)

The more assumption you can make restricting the possibilities, the easier it would be to write a parser. Without some pretty restrictive assumptions it gets very complicated to try and parse and take into account the different possible ways to join multiple tables, etc. But it is possible.

You could use Oracle's documentation to see all of the possible cases you'll have to deal with. [Oracle doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm)